# Determining "last" element for each level in django-mptt

Tags: django, django-mptt

I'm trying to generate a list akin to:

```
<ul>
    <li>Parent 1
        <ul>
            <li>Child 1</li>
            <li>Child 2</li>
            <li class="last">Child 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Parent 2
        <ul>
            <li>Child 1</li>
            <li>Child 2</li>
            <li class="last">Child 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="last">Parent 3
        <ul>
            <li>Child 1</li>
            <li>Child 2</li>
            <li class="last">Child 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I originally just did:

```
<ul>
    {% recursetree mytree %}
    <li class="{% if not node.get_next_sibling %}last{% endif %}">
        {{ node }}
        {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
        <ul>
            {{ children }}
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </li>
</ul>
```

However, the call to `node.get_next_sibling` results in an extra query for each item. Obviously, that's not ideal. So I tried using `tree_info` and `structure.closed_levels` to determine the last item:

```
{% for node,structure in mytree|tree_info %}
    {% if structure.new_level %}<ul><li>{% else %}</li><li>{% endif %}
        <li class="{% if structure.closed_levels|length > 0 %}last{% endif %}">
            {{ node }}
    {% for level in structure.closed_levels %}</li></ul>{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This works great, except the last root level item does not get the "last" class, because its `structure.closed_levels` is always an empty list. (It really only works for child items).

I'm sure I'm not the first to need to accomplish something similar, so I'm hoping someone here might have a solution already.

Comment: Haha. FWIW, it's *much* easier to add a class to the "first" item than the "last". Just have to alter my CSS a little to compensate for that. Still interested in finding out a way to label the "last" item though.

Comment: Snarky answer: `$('ul li:last-child').addClass('last')`

Comment: Haha. Yeah, I thought of that too, but it's a positioning thing (need to remove margin from last item), so it would break if JS was disabled.

Comment: How likely is it that you're using IE6?  Less than 1% of the US is still using IE6.  I mean, if that's the concern, then the CSS last-child ought to work just as well.  Or are you worried that CSS will also be disabled?

Comment: Actually, IE7 also doesn't support `:last-child` either, and while we're not worried about IE6, IE7 unfortunately is still relevant.

Comment: We use mptt in merengue project http://www.merengueproject.org/ and this works. If you are interested you can download the code. See this code http://dev.merengueproject.org/browser/trunk/merengueproj/merengue/section/templates/section/inc.item_menu_tag.html

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you should be able to get the info you need from the MPTT order info. Here's a [good intro to how MPTT works](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database/) (linked from the django-mptt docs). The key is keeping a reference to the parent around, so you can check whether your node's "right" attribute is one less than your parent's "left".

django-mptt special-cases the root nodes, to let you have multiple trees. If you're iterating over the nodes in a single tree, something like this should work (though I haven't tested):

```
<ul class="root">
    {% recursetree nodes %}
        <li class="{% if parent == None or node.rgt|plusone == parent.lft %}last{% endif %}">
            {{ node.name }}
            {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
                {% with node as parent %}
                <ul class="children">
                    {{ children }}
                </ul>
                {% endwith %}
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endrecursetree %}
</ul>
```

If, however, "nodes" holds a list of all your roots, you'll need to catch that explicitly. Something like this should do the trick:

```
{% with nodes|last as lastnode %}
<ul class="root">
    {% recursetree nodes %}
        <li class="{% if node == lastnode or parent and node.rgt|plusone == parent.lft %}last{% endif %}">
            {{ node.name }}
            {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
                {% with node as parent %}
                <ul class="children">
                    {{ children }}
                </ul>
                {% endwith %}
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endrecursetree %}
</ul>
{% endwith %}
```

You'll notice that the code above references a "plusone" template filter. Something like this should do:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def plusone(value):
    return value + 1
```

All that being said, this is a little too much template computation for my liking. If this is something you're doing regularly, it's probably wise to wrap it up in a custom template tag.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the`{{forloop.last}}`
or `{{if 1 == forloop.revcounter}}`
2nd last would be `{{if 2 == forloop.revcounter}}`

to add classes with django logic...

if you just want to add styles you can use css selecotrs `:last-child` instead of adding a class

css selectors to work for jquery if you need it for javascript and are using jquery